# (role ansible) error command .compile --options

Tags: ansible

I write role for compiling ffmpeg with cuda.
if I compile on terminal is ok, if i run role I have error.
My role is [ffmpeg-cuda](https://github.com/mikysal78/ffmpeg-cuda).
Where can the error be?

Error:

> failed: [pc-fisso] (item=./configure --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-libopencv --disable-outdev=sdl2 --disable-podpages --disable-sndio --disable-stripping --enable-libaom --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-gcrypt --disable-gnutls --enable-openssl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx265 --enable-libzimg --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-nonfree --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-vaapi --enable-libmfx --enable-libvmaf --disable-altivec --enable-nvenc --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64) => {
>       "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
>       "changed": true, 
>       "cmd": [
>           "./configure", 
>           "--disable-decoder=amrnb", 
>           "--disable-decoder=libopenjpeg", 
>           "--disable-libopencv", 
>           "--disable-outdev=sdl2", 
>           "--disable-podpages", 
>           "--disable-sndio", 
>           "--disable-stripping", 
>           "--enable-libaom", 
>           "--enable-avfilter", 
>           "--enable-avresample", 
>           "--enable-gcrypt", 
>           "--disable-gnutls", 
>           "--enable-openssl", 
>           "--enable-gpl", 
>           "--enable-libass", 
>           "--enable-libbluray", 
>           "--enable-libbs2b", 
>           "--enable-libcaca", 
>           "--enable-libcdio", 
>           "--enable-libcodec2", 
>           "--enable-libfdk-aac", 
>           "--enable-libfontconfig", 
>           "--enable-libfreetype", 
>           "--enable-libfribidi", 
>           "--enable-libgme", 
>           "--enable-libgsm", 
>           "--enable-libilbc", 
>           "--enable-libkvazaar", 
>           "--enable-libmp3lame", 
>           "--enable-libopenh264", 
>           "--enable-libopenjpeg", 
>           "--enable-libopenmpt", 
>           "--enable-libopus", 
>           "--enable-libpulse", 
>           "--enable-librubberband", 
>           "--enable-libshine", 
>           "--enable-libsnappy", 
>           "--enable-libsoxr", 
>           "--enable-libspeex", 
>           "--enable-libtesseract", 
>           "--enable-libtheora", 
>           "--enable-libvidstab", 
>           "--enable-libvorbis", 
>           "--enable-libvpx", 
>           "--enable-libx265", 
>           "--enable-libzimg", 
>           "--enable-libxvid", 
>           "--enable-libzvbi", 
>           "--enable-nonfree", 
>           "--enable-opencl", 
>           "--enable-opengl", 
>           "--enable-postproc", 
>           "--enable-pthreads", 
>           "--enable-shared", 
>           "--enable-version3", 
>           "--enable-libwebp", 
>           "--enable-libx264", 
>           "--enable-libdc1394", 
>           "--enable-vaapi", 
>           "--enable-libmfx", 
>           "--enable-libvmaf", 
>           "--disable-altivec", 
>           "--enable-nvenc", 
>           "--enable-cuda", 
>           "--enable-cuvid", 
>           "--enable-cuda-nvcc", 
>           "--enable-libnpp", 
>           "--extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include", 
>           "--extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64"
>       ], 
>       "delta": "0:00:04.148852", 
>       "end": "2019-12-03 22:33:09.658905", 
>       "invocation": {
>           "module_args": {
>               "_raw_params": "./configure --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-libopencv --disable-outdev=sdl2 --disable-podpages --disable-sndio --disable-stripping --enable-libaom --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-gcrypt --disable-gnutls --enable-openssl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx265 --enable-libzimg --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-nonfree --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-vaapi --enable-libmfx --enable-libvmaf --disable-altivec --enable-nvenc --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64", 
>               "_uses_shell": false, 
>               "argv": null, 
>               "chdir": "/opt/ffmpeg", 
>               "creates": null, 
>               "executable": null, 
>               "removes": null, 
>               "stdin": null, 
>               "stdin_add_newline": true, 
>               "strip_empty_ends": true, 
>               "warn": true
>           }
>       }, 
>       "item": "./configure --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-libopencv --disable-outdev=sdl2 --disable-podpages --disable-sndio --disable-stripping --enable-libaom --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-gcrypt --disable-gnutls --enable-openssl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx265 --enable-libzimg --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-nonfree --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-vaapi --enable-libmfx --enable-libvmaf --disable-altivec --enable-nvenc --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64", 
>       "msg": "non-zero return code", 
>       "rc": 1, 
>       "start": "2019-12-03 22:33:05.510053", 
>       "stderr": "", 
>       "stderr_lines": [], 
>       "stdout": "ERROR: failed checking for nvcc.\n\nIf you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest\nversion from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the\nffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.\nInclude the log file \"ffbuild/config.log\" produced by configure as this will help\nsolve the problem.", 
>       "stdout_lines": [
>           "ERROR: failed checking for nvcc.", 
>           "", 
>           "If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest", 
>           "version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the", 
>           "ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.", 
>           "Include the log file \"ffbuild/config.log\" produced by configure as this will help", 
>           "solve the problem."
>       ]
>   }
>   Michele

Comment: https://pastebin.com/yUTmAAd9

Comment: Hi Michele, welcome to SO. Please use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59163143/edit) to edit your post to include relevant details, since having the content of your question live on another website defeats the purpose of SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your interactive shell has a different `$PATH` than the ansible connection does; running `which nvcc` in your interactive shell will tell you the directory that you need to add to the `$PATH` for that task.

That said, based on seeing [the `/etc/profile.d/cuda.sh`](https://github.com/mikysal78/ffmpeg-cuda/blob/master/tasks/main.yml#L52) above the compile task, it seems you might want to change the task to be a `shell:` and source that file first:

```
- name: compile ffmpeg
  shell: |
    set -e
    . /etc/profile.d/cuda.sh
    ./configure {{ ffmpeg_compile_options }}
    make -j$(nproc)
    make install
    make distclean
  args:
    chdir: "{{ source_dir }}/ffmpeg"
```

You would have needed to change it from `command:` to `shell:` anyway because of that `-j$(nproc)` which is a *shell interpolation* and thus if you had used `command:` it would have tried to run `make` with a literal argument of `-j$(nproc)`